# android.app.RemoteServiceException with high crash rate in android vitals

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-messaging, android-handler, android-7.1-nougat

I have been observing the following issue on my android vitals page but have no idea what is this related to or what am I missing in my app that is causing this.
After doing a bunch of investigations I found this is related to stale resource ids after the app package is updated and the GCM keeps using the old ids thus throws this exception. I am using GCM in my app but I have no code where I am passing the resource id to the GCM token.

Need help to understand what and where to investigate to fix this issue. It is a pressing thind for my app right now as with the highest crash hits.

> This is observed only in Android 6.0 and above for me with Android 7.1
>   with the maximum crash hits.

```
.android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6334)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```